# Where do these safari pop up come from?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

So where do these come from?  Are they a weakness in the browser, in this case safari or what?  Every now and again I’ll get these on safari then if I go to Firefox to the same site they don’t pop up....  I then will go back to safari, clear cache and all history and can go back to the same site and they will come back.  Is it a weakness in the site I’m going to or what?

[image: desktop screenshot]

Comment: It could be the particular site you are visiting or you could have some malware. I hear MalwareBytes works good for such things and I believe you can download and usie it for free for a limited time. Might be worth trying

Comment: Tks. the iPad version of malware bytes seems very different than the computer version and to be honest I couldn't tell what it was doing.  Very limited in setting and seems to be an all or nothing app.  While I didn't get the pop up with the app installed, I have not gotten it again w/o it either....  I have had these from time to time, same kind of pop up but with other sites and in talking with the admin folks at the sites, they seem to think they originate with the site...  who knows.